# What is faster: strlen or filesize?

Tags: php

Consider some file, which content is already obtained by `file_get_contents('file.ext')`, and stored in some variable `$a`.

Task is to change last character of the string.

What will be faster?

```
$a[strlen($a) - 1] = 'b';
```

or

```
$a[filesize('file.ext') - 1] = 'b';
```

I suppose that filesize value is somehow cached by file system, or first and last address of the memory, file occupied by is known, so it just subtracts second from first.

---

I made some benchmark, the first value is number of seconds that takes `strlen`, the second `filesize` here is the result:

```
9 -6
2.5 -5

2 - 5
2.8 - 5

2.4 - 5
4.19 - 5

1 - 5
2.9 - 5

9 - 6
2.69 - 5

9 - 6
2.9 - 6
```

So, it seems, like `strlen` is faster, but as @nice_dev mentioned `filesize` is called at `file_get_contents`, so probably I need to use `filesize` with `fopen` or something like that.

Comment: [The ubiquitous comment for all similar questions](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: [`filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#:~:text=bytes%27%3B%0A%0A%3F%3E-,Notes,-%C2%B6) does cache the results but as of now, I can't conclusively say that `filesize` gets called when you call `file_get_contents`. Looking at the comparison, both should compare evenly with each other.

Comment: [There's a LOT of misinformation here, which I want to correct! Many people have warned against using strlen(), because it is "super slow". Well, that was probably true in old versions of PHP. But as of PHP7 that's definitely no longer true. It's now SUPER fast!](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#120632)

Comment: To the best of my understanding, [PHP stores the string’s length in the underlying struct](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php5/zvals/basic_structure.html), so I’d expect it to be fast and propbably optimized to a literal in some contexts, whereas anything with the file system could involve potentially going to hardware which would be slower.

Comment: Aren't both of your approaches flawed if a multibyte character is in the string? Is question just about the functions or your actual usage?

Comment: `filesize` returns the filesize in bytes. This includes multibyte characters, spaces, newlines, etc.  `strlen` will count the amount of bytes of a string, which does the same as filesize on a byte level except for multibyte characters. You will then need `mb_strlen()`.  Or if you really want to to wild use a preg_replace.

Comment: @user3783243 and @Leroy, yes, I consider multibyte strings. @user3783243 for usage: I just understood, that it probably would be faster if instead of parsing json array, stored in file, when I need to add new element there, I just write to that file with `APPEND` flag an encoded json object I need to put in, with `,` at the end. When I need to read that json, (and here what current post is intended for), I just read the file and replace last character (i.e. `,`) with bracket character `]`

Answer (score 0):

If we make some reasonable **assumptions** about how PHP represents your data internally, strlen() should always be faster:

1. Most languages store the length of strings directly with the variable, so getting the string length should be about as fast as accessing the already-in-memory value of any number.
2. You could test your assumption about caching filesize using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), filter on your php process, and see how many file accesses it does in a loop where you call filesize().  But...
3. Even under the best-case-scenario, if we assume file_get_contents() caches the file size when it loads it, filesize() will still need to take the string filename, perhaps convert it to a normalized form (replacing '../', converting '\' to '/') and then do a lookup in a HashMap to find the size.  This will always be slower than #1.

Comment: But, if we are considering string, obtained from read file, we have `filesize` call anyway, so in this particular case, `strlen` call will be excess

Comment: Suppose file_get_contents() calls filesize and caches the result in memory.  If you call filesize() again, retrieving that cached file size will still be slower than strlen() getting the cached length of the string.  At least given the assumptions I outlined above.